# OpenCV matchTemplate finds same shapen multiple times - Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

My questions is an extention of a question that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156473/find-all-locations-of-image-in-larger-image-in-python/61156830#61156830).

I'm using matchTemplate to find circles on a page. This is the result:

[image]

I want to find the locations of the mid-points of these rectangles, which I can do with the coordinates of the corners of the rectangles. I put a list inside the four loop, so the code could catch the coordinates of the rectangles. This it the result:

```
[..., 
 [(144, 187), (539, 571)],
 [(145, 187), (540, 571)],
 [(146, 187), (541, 571)],
 [(147, 187), (542, 571)],
 [(148, 187), (543, 571)],
 [(149, 187), (544, 571)],
 [(150, 187), (545, 571)],
 [(151, 187), (546, 571)],
 [(152, 187), (547, 571)],
 [(133, 188), (528, 572)],
 [(134, 188), (529, 572)],
 [(135, 188), (530, 572)],
 [(136, 188), (531, 572)],
 [(137, 188), (532, 572)],
 [(138, 188), (533, 572)],
 [(139, 188), (534, 572)],
 [(140, 188), (535, 572)],
 [(141, 188), (536, 572)],
 [(142, 188), (537, 572)],
 [(143, 188), (538, 572)],
 [(144, 188), (539, 572)],
 [(145, 188), (540, 572)],
 [(146, 188), (541, 572)],
 [(147, 188), (542, 572)],
 [(148, 188), (543, 572)],
 [(149, 188), (544, 572)],
 ...]
```

This is just a snippet: there are hundreds of lines like this which gives me the info that matchTemplate finds the same circle over and over again. I was expecting only five sets of corner-values.

First I started to remove all double values in the list, but since there are many values remaining after that I still have the same problem.

Does anyone have a way to find only one set of corner-values for each circle (which is most certainly correct) so that I can use that value?

I hope my question is clear and someone can help.

Regards,
Ganesh

---

**EDIT**: my question is still unclear, so I hope this edit will give some clarity.

First, I want my code to be able to find the circles on the image, using OpenCV matchingTemplate. I have the code, the image and the template here:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#load image into variable
img_rgb = cv2.imread('example_scan.jpg')

#load template
template = cv2.imread('example_template.jpg')

List = []

#read height and width of template image
w, h = template.shape[0], template.shape[1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.95
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for i in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    location = (i[0] + w, i[1] + h)
    List.append([i, location])

    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, i, location, (0,255,0), 20)

img_rgb = cv2.resize(img_rgb,(800,600))
cv2.imshow("result",img_rgb)
cv2.waitKey(10000)
```

[image]

[image]

Normally I use a threshold of 0.8, but for this example I use 0.95 for more clearity. This is then the result:

[image]

This shows that the code does indeed work. Now, here is the issue.

I want to determine the centerpoint of the reactangle that is shown. This can be determined using a simple code which uses the corners of the rectangle:

```
xCenter = (i[0] + i[0] + w)/2
yCenter = (i[1] + i[1] + w)/2
```

I can use this code inside the for-loop, which gives me the center xy-coordinate of each ractangle that is found.

When I print this xy-coordinate (and also the List) I would expect one xy-coordinate, but instead I can see a whole list of coordinates which only differ a little bit from each other:

```
#Locations of the center xy-coordinates:
(1527.5, 770.5)
(1525.5, 771.5)
(1526.5, 771.5)
(1527.5, 771.5)
(1528.5, 771.5)
(1529.5, 771.5)
(1525.5, 772.5)
(1526.5, 772.5)
(1527.5, 772.5)
(1528.5, 772.5)
(1529.5, 772.5)
(1524.5, 773.5)
(1525.5, 773.5)
(1526.5, 773.5)
(1527.5, 773.5)
(1528.5, 773.5)
(1529.5, 773.5)
(1530.5, 773.5)
(1525.5, 774.5)
(1526.5, 774.5)
(1527.5, 774.5)
(1528.5, 774.5)
(1529.5, 774.5)
(1525.5, 775.5)
(1526.5, 775.5)
(1527.5, 775.5)
(1528.5, 775.5)
(1529.5, 775.5)
(1527.5, 776.5)
```

So what happens is that the template is found multiple times on the same spot, with only a small difference in coordinates (around 5px).

What I want is that the code returns only one center xy-coordinate, for which I need only one rectangle. My question is: how can this be done? Is there a code that is able for example to recognize the small difference and would be able to filter them out?

I hope the question is much clearer now.

Regards,
Ganesh

Comment: Your question needs more clarity for us to understand what your issue is and your code and template image. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I believe the center of Rectangle is the center of the circle, is my assumption is correct in your image?

Comment: Hi @fmw42 , I made changes under EDIT, I hope my problem is much clearer now.

Comment: The issue is that a simple threshold will find lots of points near the best match point. On way to solve that is to loop over the thresholded pixel coordinates and filter out those within some radius. Then repeat for the next highest value and throw out is neighbors. Etc. for as many results as you want or until you exhaust your thresholded list.

Comment: Hi @fmw42 , thanks for the response. I think I understand you, but do you have a code example for this?

Comment: No. Not in OpenCV. I have done that in Imagemagick by masking. But in OpenCV you can do that or you can just filter the from the coordinates. If you want to see my Imagemagick way, see http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/maxima/index.php